# How to detect when the last file of the manifest file is updated?

Tags: javascript, html, offline-caching, offlineapps, manifest.cache

I'm building an Offline HTML5's App, which has several pages inside (10 to be more specific). When I need to change any of these pages, I simply change the manifest file to instruct the browser to update all files (As the HTML5 documentation recommends). But here is the problem that nobody talks about:

While the browser is downloading the files, my dear users rushes into the app and start using it, then they complain that the changes did not take place. After hours of testing, I realized that the browser is slower than my users. So here is my question:

How to detect when the last file of the manifest file is fully updated? or in other words, how to stop my user to stop using the app until the last file in the manifest is fully downloaded?

I don't find anything on the Web about this issue

Is there any Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the [`cached` event](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#event-appcache-cached) in the [application cache API](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#application-cache-api).